# error: `boost' has not been declared

Tags: c++, linux, boost, centos

I'm trying to use boost libraries in my C++ application. I'm trying to compile it using g++ with different options.e.g `g++ -I /usr/include/boost/filesystem/ -o test.out test.cpp` however it always prompt  `error: 'boost' has not been declared`.

And here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    string line;
    string fileName = "Read.txt";
    ifstream file;
    string str; 
    file.open(fileName.c_str());
    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    vector<string>  fileLines;

    fileLines.clear();
    while (getline(file, str))
    {
        fileLines.push_back(line);
    }
    cout << "Total Line count:"<<fileLines.size()<<endl;
    fileLines.clear();
    cout << "Total Line count:"<<fileLines.size()<<endl;
    boost::filesystem::path p("/tmp/foo.txt");


    return 0;
}
```

I will be glad if you help me to fix this.

P.S. I'm compiling my application in Centos 4.7 and It contains Boost version 1.32 according to `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp`

**Update:**

I also commented boost instruction, but there is some problem with includes: `boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @drescherjm updated. thanks for notice.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have not yet installed the boost header files that you need for includes. Since you are on CentOS, you need to:

```
yum install boost-devel
```

That will place the header file you want in:

```
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp
```

Since you are using `boost::filesystem::path`, you should change your `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` to `#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>`. Since `-I /usr/include` is passed to gcc by default, you do not need the `-I /usr/include/boost/filesystem`, unless you changed the include to `path.hpp`. However, this would be dangerous because another library may have the same header file name and then you may include the wrong header.

Comment: I got boost-devel package installed. but thanks for details

Comment: Oh yes, I totally missed the `boost::filesystem::path` which meant you were referencing a different include. Updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

Accodring to header files in my Centos Linux, I changed

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

to

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
```

And also compiled my program with special link options:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.out  -lboost_filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
   `g++ -std=c++11 -Os -Wall -pedantic test.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o test`

I had the same problem

Let me know if is works

best regards,

Comment: I'm using gcc version 3.4.6. It does not support `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: Did you try without -std=c++11?

Comment: It's not compiling, adding linker commands won't help with that problem.